# How to draw a angle (three points) in WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml, path, geometry, point

I plan to create a software about drawing angles. And I really have no idea about how to represent the correct three point position.

For example, I need a someway that I introduced the value 90, I get the righ position of the three point.

Until the momment, I just need some help or ideas about how to draw correctly the line or points with XAML.

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Path object to draw those lines... and the formula:

var CoordinateX = Math.Cos(Angle);
var CoordinateY = Math.Sin(Angle);

Angle in radians.

Comment: Could you show an example with that formula using XAML? That is the part which I'm a bit lost

Comment: Well... you can't write C# code in XAML (or at least you're not supposed to). The easiest way, for me, is to create some sort of user control with your angle-drawing-thing already created. Add a property to specify the requested angle and, after the given calculation, change you Path object to reflect the new angle.